# How can I order posts in descending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a blog type site, and I'd like the posts to be displayed newest first(descending order) Ive tried a few different things and haven't been able to figure it out. This is my current code:

post.html.erb

```
<%= @posts.each do |post|%>
<div>
    <p><%= avatar_for(post.user, size: 40) %>
    <%= link_to post.username, post.user %></p>
    <h2>
        <%= link_to post.title, post %>
    </h2>

</div>
    <% end%>
```

post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController 
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    def posts
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end


    def new 
        @post = Post.new 
    end 

    def create 
        @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
        if @post.save 
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
        else 
            render :new 
        end
    end 

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end


    private 
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :all_tags)
    end 
end
```

Comment: That should work. And you don't need to call `all` though. Either `Post.order('created_at DESC')` or `Post.order(created_at: :desc)` should work.

Comment: just a small fix, in your `posts` method you're declaring `@post` variable but in the ERB file you're calling `@posts`. That should be giving you a Nil error. Declare `@posts` (plural)

Answer (score 4):

I believe, based on the [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering), that the syntax you're looking for is:

```
  Post.order(created_at: :desc)
```

See if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should be `@posts` as you are calling `@posts` in you `post.html.erb` to retrieve and display all the posts:

```
def posts
 @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Comment: I actually forgot to fix that when i posted this, but it still wont work. Instead it will render the post several times and then prints the array in between the posts.

Comment: @DavidK remove the `=` before the `@posts.each` from your view. Is that solves the problem?

Comment: It got rid of the array, but the posts are still being render 3 times each, and not in descending order.

Comment: Restart your  `rails server` and refresh the page and try again tell me if that still happen.

Comment: No luck. still rendering the posts 3 times and not in the right order.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark. But, your OP shows `post.html.erb`. Was that a typo? Or, do you also have a `posts.html.erb` file? Fishing here...

Comment: @jvillian If it was `post.html.erb` then he should have the error of **missing template** but he is not having that.

Comment: Agreed. Although, it's not impossible that he did some renaming along the way and may be working on the wrong file. I was just befuddled because your code looked right. It's happened to me before. So, I thought I'd ask. Just checking the edge cases. Apologies if unhelpful.

Comment: @DavidK As comment section is going lengthy I have created a chat room we will discuss it there [Chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122243/rails)

Answer (score 1):

The method should look like

```
def posts
    # Plural @posts
    @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

Just a small fix, in your posts method you're declaring `@post` variable but in the ERB file you're calling `@posts`.
That should be giving you a Nil error. Declare `@posts` (plural), and then your ERB file with better indentation:

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div>
    <p>
      <%= avatar_for(post.user, size: 40) %>
      <%= link_to post.username, post.user %>
    </p>
    <h2>
      <%= link_to post.title, post %>
    </h2>
  </div>
<% end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this question hasn't been answered yet:

It looks like the problem is coming from the name of the method in your PostsController.

You're expecting to have access to @posts from a method called posts, but your file name for the view you're trying to render is post.html.erb. I believe it should be posts.html.erb.

Why not call it index? That's the Rails convention.

As others have said, the query is correct. Hope this helps.